# Is it possible to do a soft write in Firebase Database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to do a soft write in Firebase Database for test purposes? Alternatively, how would I run tests on the Firebase Database while it is being used in production?

Comment: Use object mocking for unit testing.  Never test in production - use a different Firebase project for development and testing.

Comment: That's what I'll do. Any particular reason why the engineers have not built such feature? It would be useful.

Comment: TBH I've never heard of a modern cloud-based database system that allows for a "soft write".  It sounds like what you're looking for is a local database emulator used for local integration testing, which is something the team is investigating.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that Firebase handles soft write by itself, i.e. changes you make when **Unit Testing** are not reflected on the console.

But you can do it splicitly also with: [Database.goOffline()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabase(im)goOffline)

Comment: No. This will take the database offline but when it goes online it will synchronize the offline data with the online data and that's what the OP didn't want to do.